# Paperclip with s3 not working with Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm using Paperclip and s3 for photo uploads for my Rails app. It works in development but not in production. When I try to upload a photo, I get the generic Heroku error message: "Something went wrong".

But what went wrong!?! I have no idea.

I can create new records if I don't upload a photo so it's definitely something with s3.

I've followed this [tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3) accurately (in my opinion) and it just doesn't work.

Let me know if you need to see any code I have. Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Ok I fixed the problem.

First I created a YAML file:

```
development:
  bucket: bucket-name
  access_key_id: key-id
  secret_access_key: access-id
test:
  bucket: bucket-name
  access_key_id: key-id
  secret_access_key: access-id
production:
  bucket: bucket-name
  access_key_id: key-id
  secret_access_key: access-id
```

Then I added this to my user model user.rb file:

```
has_attached_file :photo,
                  :storage => :s3, 
                  :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
                  :path => "user/:attachment/:style/:id.:extension"
```

That did the trick.

Comment: What does your `heroku logs -t` give you when you try to do it?